# How do I configure POP3 users in Mercury Mail server in XAMPP for Windows?

Tags: configuration, xampp

I am using [XAMPP for Windows](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), and I have enabled Mercury Mail Server.  I am really only doing this because I need an SMTP server for sending mail; I don't need to receive any mail or use any POP3 accounts.  In the XAMPP Security Panel, I get the following error:

> The test user (newuser) for Mercury Mail server (POP3) has an old password (wampp)
>   Please check and perhaps edit all users and passwords in the the Mercury Mail server configuration!

How do I do this?  I really just want to disable POP3 altogether, or maybe just remove all POP3 users.  I have searched Google and I have searched the XAMPP forums, but I can't seem to find how to do this.  The XAMPP Control Panel has a button to go to administration of Mercury Mail Server, but it does nothing!  The XAMPP security page even tells me:

> For FileZilla FTP und Mercury Mail, you must fix all security problems by yourself! Sorry.

So I'm turning to SF for help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out a solution after some digging around.  If anyone knows whether or not this is the best way of doing this, please let me know.

In C:\xampp\MercuryMail\MAIL, there is a folder for each user.  If you want to change the user's password, just edit the PASSWD.PM file in their directory.  To delete a user, delete their directory, then edit PMAIL.USR (in the MAIL directory) and remove that user's line.  Restart the Mercury Mail service after making changes.